# Unwanted CefSharp related files in a Nuget Package

Tags: c#, nuget, cefsharp

We have a NuGet project that consumes CefSharp. We recently upgraded CefSharp from 49.0.1 to 117.2.40 and noticed the project went from 105KB to 230MB in size when we packaged it into NuGet. We checked the NUPKG file with NugetPackageExplroer and noticed there is Content and ContentFiles folder with all the CefSharp dependencies.

[image]

We didn't change anything else or the project file. I then tested with other versions of CefSharp to see if they have the Content folder. Looks like from 88.2.90,all the newer versions have content and contentFiles folders with all the dependencies and all the versions prior 88.2.90 don't have the folders.

Also, we noticed there are warning messages like this:

C:\Users\build_made.nuget\packages\nuget.build.tasks.pack\5.4.0\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5): warning NU5100: The assembly 'content\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.

I didn't see the warning messages with old versions also, only 88.2.90 and newer versions.

Below is PackageReference in the project file

```
 <PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64">
      <Version>117.2.4</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>compile; build; contentfiles; analyzers</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x86">
      <Version>117.2.4</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>compile; build; contentfiles; analyzers</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Common">
      <Version>117.2.40</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>compile; build; contentfiles; analyzers</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.WinForms">
      <Version>117.2.40</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>compile; build; contentfiles; analyzers</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

We package the dependencies with our installer to distribute them. Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent creating Content folder? We want to minimize our NuGet file size.

Comment: Already asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4616